# Data validating from Telegram Web App and CryptoJS

Tags: telegram-bot, cryptojs

I try to rewrite [validation code](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app) to JS + cryptoJS:

```js
var secret_key = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(bot.token, "WebAppData");
var key = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(initData, secret_key)
// initData it is - Telegram.WebApp.initData
if(key==hash){
    // validated
}
    
// I have also tried converting 'key' to hex:
key = key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
key == hash // always false too
```

But my validation is always false.

What fixes are needed?

Comment: Did you try checking the type of `key` and `hash` using the `typeof()` function?

Comment: I am trying console.log(key + " - " + hash) - it is not same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

This is a ported version of the Python solution found in [`Aiogram`](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/3b66a2b2e0a90ffc80582be3d1ef0e7045ce51fa/aiogram/utils/web_app.py#L8)

```js
import HmacSHA256 from "crypto-js/hmac-sha256";
import Hex from "crypto-js/enc-hex";

function checkWebAppSignature(token, initData) {
  // It is not clear from the documentation weather is URL
  // escaped or not, maybe you will need to uncomment this
  // initData = decodeURIComponent(initData)
  // Parse URL Query
  const q = new URLSearchParams(initData);
  // Extract the hash
  const hash = q.get("hash");

  // Re encode in accordance to the documentation. Remember
  // to remove hash before.
  q.delete("hash");
  const v = Array.from(q.entries());
  v.sort(([aN, aV], [bN, bV]) => aN.localeCompare(bN));
  const data_chack_string = v.map(([n, v]) => `${n}=${v}`).join("\n");

  // Perform the algorithm provided with the documentation
  var secret_key = HmacSHA256(token, "WebAppData").toString(Hex);
  var key = HmacSHA256(data_chack_string, secret_key).toString(Hex);

  return key === hash;
}
```

Here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-glade-j3hwdm?file=/src/index.js:0-908)

### Clarifying the documentation

Honestly, the documentation is quite twisted and can be improved. But there are some hints to what may be going on.

#### 1) Format

> To validate data received via the Web App, one should send the data from the Telegram.WebApp.initData field to the bot's backend. The data is a **query string**, which is composed of a series of field-value pairs.

> Data-check-string is a chain of all received fields, sorted alphabetically, in the format key= with a line feed character ('\n', 0x0A) used as separator ...

So `initData` is a URL Query `name=One&surname=Two` where the expected `data_check_string` should be new line separated `name=One\nsurname=Two`

#### 2) Hash is included

This is not explicated in the documentation, but `initData` includes the `hash` in the form `name=One&surname=Two&...&hash=...`. Being almost [impossible to include the hash of the document in the document itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432669) hints at the fact that the string `initData` is **not the one** being hashed. In [`Aiogram`](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/3b66a2b2e0a90ffc80582be3d1ef0e7045ce51fa/aiogram/utils/web_app.py#L8) you find a confirmation of this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is working variant with "node:crypto" module. Thanks to [@Newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72985407/22450547) and [@mitenka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76875631/22450547) answers.

```js
import { createHmac } from "node:crypto";

function parseInitData(initData: string) {
  const q = new URLSearchParams(initData);
  const hash = q.get("hash");
  q.delete("hash");
  const v = Array.from(q.entries());
  v.sort(([aN], [bN]) => aN.localeCompare(bN));
  const data_check_string = v.map(([n, v]) => `${n}=${v}`).join("\n");
  return { hash, data_check_string };
}

function checkSignature(bot_token: string, initData: string) {
  const { hash, data_check_string } = parseInitData(initData);

  const secret_key = createHmac("sha256", "WebAppData").update(bot_token).digest();
  const key = createHmac("sha256", secret_key)
    .update(data_check_string)
    .digest("hex");

  return key === hash;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, This should have been the answer since the one marked as answer doesn't actually work

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude hash parameter from `initData` before computing hash for comparison and order other parameters in alphabetical order. Also you do need to convert key(computed hash to hex), cause hash present in initData from telegram is in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you need, but you can still check initData in PHP.  Here I found a great solution [TgWebValid](https://github.com/CrazyTapok-bit/tgWebValid)

Answer (score 0):

function transformInitData(initData) { return Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(initData));} async function validate(data, botToken) { const encoder = new TextEncoder() const checkString = await Object.keys(data) .filter((key) => key !== "hash") .map((key) => `${key}=${data[key]}`) .sort() .join("\n") const secretKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", encoder.encode('WebAppData'), { name: "HMAC", hash: "SHA-256" }, true, ["sign"]) const secret = await crypto.subtle.sign("HMAC", secretKey, encoder.encode(botToken) const signatureKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", secret, { name: "HMAC", hash: "SHA-256" }, true, ["sign"]) const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign("HMAC", signatureKey, encoder.encode(checkString)) const hex = [...new Uint8Array(signature)].map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('') return data.hash === hex }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using:

```js
// Transforms Telegram.WebApp.initData string into object
    function transformInitData(initData: string): TransformInitData {
      return Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(initData));
    }
    
    async function generateHex(data: TransformInitData, botToken: string): Promise<string> {
      const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      const checkString = await Object.keys(data)
        .filter((key) => key !== 'hash')
        .map((key) => `${key}=${data[key]}`)
        .sort()
        .join('\n');
      const secretKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        encoder.encode('WebAppData'),
        { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256' },
        true,
        ['sign']
      );
      const secret = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        secretKey,
        encoder.encode(botToken)
      );
      const signatureKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        secret,
        { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256' },
        true,
        ['sign']
      );
      const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        signatureKey,
        encoder.encode(checkString)
      );
    
      const hex = [...new Uint8Array(signature)]
        .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
        .join('');
    
      return hex;
    }
    
    export async function onRequest(context: any) {
      try {
        const payload = await context.request.json();
        const dataCheckString = payload.hash;
        const data = transformInitData(dataCheckString);
        const botToken = context.env.BOT_TOKEN;
      
        const hex = await generateHex(data, botToken);
        if(data['hash'] === hex) {
          return await context.next();
        }
      
        const json = JSON.stringify({ message: 'not authorized' });
        return new Response(json, { status: 403 });
        
      } catch (err) {
        return new Response('Server Error', { status: 500 });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Newbie, your answer helped me a lot. In my case it looks slightly different tho (especially when it comes to `secret` hashing), so I'll publish my solution.

```js
import { HmacSHA256, Hex } from "crypto-js";

const params = c.req.query();
const { hash } = params;

delete params["hash"];

// Sort params by key alphabetically and then join them with new line symbol (\n).
let dataCheckString = Object.keys(params)
  .sort()
  .map((key) => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
  .join("\n");

const secret = HmacSHA256(c.env.BOT_TOKEN, "WebAppData");
const calculatedHash = HmacSHA256(dataCheckString, secret).toString(Hex);
console.log(hash === calculatedHash);
```